# Known Issues in WordPress When Upgrading PHP to ver 7

Tags: php, multisite, mysql

I am running a WordPress Multisite Network in PHP 5.6.30 and MySQL Community Server 5.6.35

I plan to upgrade my server to PHP ver 7.1.x and MySQL to the MariaDB ver 10

Are there any issues that I need to be aware of and account for before I do such an upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

[WordPress recommends PHP7 and MariaDB 10.0 or higher](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/), so your core installation should be fine.

If you're using any third-party plugins and/or themes (including ones you've written), you would be wise to ensure that they too are compatible with PHP7. Check the respective maintainers' support streams (either the relevant plugin/theme pages on wordpress.org or the relevant sites if they're downloaded / purchased from other venues).

Comment: Thanks @PatJ. Are there any compatibility checkers that you know of that can diagnose & report issues or verify that the plugins and themes are okay?

Comment: A quick [Google search for `php 7 compatibility checker`](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+7+compatibility+checker) found the [PHP Compatibility Checker](https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-compatibility-checker/) plugin, which might be a good starting point for you.